# Is this slow-loading images question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

This question was closed for asking for code to be written, but I think it is really asking how to speed up the loading of images, which I would think is performance related, which is something that we do review.

[Speed up slow loading images?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/30080/18427)

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Agreed that the question is on topic, but why are we editing/reopening a question that is almost a year old?

Comment: because people will see it and think that these types of questions are off topic.

Comment: [This question is part of a larger discussion](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/code-review-vs-help-me-solve-my-problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is code presented, which the author claims to be in working order. The question asks for help with performance. This isn't much different from a typical Project Euler question, though it is harder to answer due to browser, network, and server interactions.

The word "fix" in the title might have been a bit strong, though.

Comment: I edited the question again. I cannot vote to reopen.

Comment: If I read correctly, this answer is suggesting the question should be re-opened, right?  I cast a vote.