# Are Monte Carlo algorithms off-topic by definition?

Tags: discussion, scope, wording

One of the key requirements for posting here is

> working code to the best of our knowledge

Where working means that the code compiles and returns correct results.

Where does that put [Monte Carlo algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_algorithm)

> whose output may be incorrect with a certain (typically small) probability.

Does that mean that they are by default off-topic? (Because they return the wrong result with a certain small probability.)

Is the definition of "working code" another one in this context and if so what should it be?

### Update

Of course it is clear that we don't want to forbid Monte Carlo code from being reviewed. However, where is the line between off- and on-topic for Monte Carlo questions?

This is probably off-topic but why:

```
int add(int a, int b) { return rand(); }
```

And where do you draw the line?

Answer (score 13):

No, they're on topic, as long as you specify that it is a monte-carlo algorithm. Ideally, you'd specify the probability of success, but doing so is optional.

Why? Because the code isn't broken; it's doing exactly as stated.

Asking us to fix a monte-carlo algorithm to be perfect is off-topic however.

---

Looking at your example: It's lacking context as to why you'd do that. That's why it's offtopic. As to whether it'd be off-topic with context? No. It'd be on-topic. I'd love to see someone explain to me why they'd need `rand()` for addition, and have it be a valid point.

---

Bottomline: **For questions including Monte Carlo algorithms, you should state that it contains a Monte Carlo algorithm, as well as why you need it.**

Comment: So it is off-topic if the code fails to hit the stated probability? Even worse: what if the OP has no idea about the probability?

Comment: hadn't thought of that... I guess the probability is optional

Comment: I have updated the question a bit and pose the same question to you as to @Simon.

Comment: Looks like a trivial task to me, why are you using monte-carlo for trivial tasks

Comment: It was just an example for a clearly off-topic Monte Carlo question to identify criteria that help determine whether a Monte Carlo question would be off-topic.

Answer (score 10):

Let's see:

1. *Is code included directly in my question?* **Yes**
2. *Am I an owner or maintainer of the code?* **Yes**
3. *Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?* **Yes**
4. *Do I want the code to be good code?* **Yes**
5. *To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?* **(See below)**
6. *Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?* **Yes**

The culprit is: *To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?*

My definition of *does the does work?* is: *Does it do what it is supposed to do and produce the expected results?*

While Monte Carlo may produce some *statistically inaccurate* results, that's the point of the algorithm.

Let's assume that they were off-topic, then where would programmers go to have code for a Monte Carlo algorithm reviewed? My point exactly. Saying that it is off-topic just because it's Monte Carlo would be silly.

---

As for how you exactly formulate the question, such as:

- I have this Monte Carlo algorithm, but I am not sure if it is correct or not
- I have this Monte Carlo algorithm, is there a better algorithm to pick?
- I have this Monte Carlo algorithm, how would you have solved it?
- I have this Monte Carlo algorithm, how can the code be improved?
- etc.

That's part of [another discussion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/code-review-vs-help-me-solve-my-problem)

Comment: Where is the line to an off-topic Monte Carlo algorithm then?

Comment: @Nobody: Depends on what question(s) you're asking.  If you aren't already confident that it works, it's off topic.  If the code just needs a bit of refactoring/cleanup, it's probably on topic.  The area in between is a big grey cloud, not a line.